# percentage of 2 numbers

Tags: android

I build a simple texteditor, I also add a percentage of reading. I think is everything ok (on my mobile and 3 emulators) but on other devices crashes.

I don't understand what is the problem. Any help?

```
public void perc(){
    float perc3;
    perc3=((a)*100)/(float)b;
    NumberFormat numberFormat = DecimalFormat.getInstance();
    numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    String formattedText = numberFormat.format(perc3);
    perc= new Double(formattedText);
}
```

Comment: Please post the logcat stack trace for the exception.

Comment: are you sure about void type? Can it be double,float or any others with a return?

Comment: On emulators doesn't crash (crashes on mobile of my friends)

Comment: Maybe that `b==0` ? (I guess this is the reason). Well you should catch any exception here, and log the result somewhere. You can invite your friends at home for a beer, and check their logs with their phones plugged on your Eclipse debugger. Anyway, you MUST find a way to have the stacktrace...

Comment: :-) my friend lives at Rome (I stay at Milan). I check that "0". The logic of code is correct? thanks!

Comment: In order to get the stack trace you have 2 options. One, catch the exception and print it to a file, and your friend can send you the file. Second, and it is an easier one but quick and dirty, ask your friend to download https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anjedi#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDIxMiwiY29tLmFuamVkaSJd and he can make a screenshot for you with the stack trace. This application enables seeing the logcat on the device itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as you state, you're sure b is never going to be 0, why don't you try a different approach to get the 2 fraction digits double? It seems less error prone and more efficient:

```
public double perc()
{
   long perc3 = Math.round( a*10000 / (double)b );
   return perc3 / (double) 100;
}
```

I hope this helps. If you still get a crash I'm quite sure it is not in this snippet of code.